# Output pandas dataframe as a multi level python dictionary to support API JSON request

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have an API that ingests time series data as a JSON request and needs the JSON in the following format:

```
[
{
    "ts": 1630116000000,
    "values": {
        "vwc1": 1.69,
        "vwc2": 1.93
        ...
    }
},
{
    "ts": 163015600000,
    "values": {
        "vwc1": 1.59,
        "vwc2": 1.97
    }
}
]
```

The **source data** is imported into python as csv and placed into a pandas dataframe:

```
                             vsys     vup      vwc1      vic1       st1      vwc2      vic2       st2      vwc3      vic3       st3      ...             st9     vwc10     vic10      st10     vwc11     vic11      st11     vwc12     vic12      st12             ts
Date Time                                                                                                                                ...                                                                                                                         
2021-08-28 12:00:00+10:00  13.350  13.348  11.38990  1691.903  19.00000  19.18203  400.4311  18.78000  19.68363  1211.360  18.91000      ...        20.89001  43.59949  1874.603  19.91000  43.66155  21054.63  19.79999  47.13536  4195.486  19.97000  1630116000000
2021-08-28 12:30:00+10:00  13.360  -1.000  11.34434  1683.595  19.10999  19.17777  400.8896  18.72000  19.67229  1211.366  18.89999      ...        20.82999  43.55956  1874.017  19.98999  43.65295  20977.79  19.79999  47.10374  4193.230  20.07001  1630117800000
2021-08-28 13:00:00+10:00  13.371  -1.000  11.30646  1733.315  19.23001  19.14365  404.5721  18.82999  19.65718  1215.523  18.92001      ...        20.91000  43.55956  1874.017  20.01001  43.67014  20995.88  19.75000  47.10374  4193.230  20.07001  1630119600000
```

I've spent most of the day trying to have my script output the source data into the correct JSON (nested dictionary) format. I've looked at to_dict and groupby and have developed the following code:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['ts'])
    payload = (df.groupby(['ts'])[cols]
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records'))
        .reset_index(name='values')
        .to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Which generates something very close to what I need:

```
[
    {
        "ts": 1630116000000,
        "values": [
            {
                "vwc1": 11.3899,
                "vwc2": 19.182029999999997
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ts": 1630117800000,
        "values": [
            {
                "vwc1": 11.344339999999999,
                "vwc2": 19.177770000000002
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ts": 1630119600000,
        "values": [
            {
                "vwc1": 11.306460000000001,
                "vwc2": 19.14365,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But the killer is the 'values' object is being generated as a **list of dictionary objects**, rather than just a **plain dictionary** (which is what the API requires as per the example JSON above).

I've read up on the to_dict method and feel the issue is perhaps with the method's orient parameter, but I cannot for the life of me get it right.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Date Time,vsys,vup,vwc1,vic1,st1,vwc2,ts
2021-08-28 12:00:00+10:00,13.350,13.348,11.38990,1691.903,19.00000,19.18203,1630116000000
2021-08-28 12:30:00+10:00,13.360,-1.000,11.34434,1683.595,19.10999,19.17777,1630117800000  
2021-08-28 13:00:00+10:00,13.371,-1.000,11.30646,1733.315,19.23001,19.14365,1630119600000"""))
df = df.set_index(['Date Time'])
```

We can use `tuple` and extract the unique value in it to avoid the `list` format and to get the expected result :

```py
>>> cols = df.columns.difference(['ts'])
>>> payload = (df.groupby(['ts'])[cols]
...     .apply(lambda x: tuple(x.to_dict(orient='records'))[0])
...     .reset_index(name='values')
...     .to_dict(orient='records'))
>>> payload
[{'ts': 1630116000000,
  'values': {'st1': 19.0,
   'vic1': 1691.903,
   'vsys': 13.35,
   'vup': 13.348,
   'vwc1': 11.3899,
   'vwc2': 19.18203}},
 {'ts': 1630117800000,
  'values': {'st1': 19.10999,
   'vic1': 1683.595,
   'vsys': 13.36,
   'vup': -1.0,
   'vwc1': 11.34434,
   'vwc2': 19.17777}},
 {'ts': 1630119600000,
  'values': {'st1': 19.23001,
   'vic1': 1733.315,
   'vsys': 13.371,
   'vup': -1.0,
   'vwc1': 11.30646,
   'vwc2': 19.14365}}]
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank-you so much tlentali, it worked perfectly. Casting the list as tuples is somethings I've never done before. Glad you were able to save my bacon!!

Comment: No worries @tlentali, though a frequent reader of Stack Overflow, very much an amateur poster. Thanks for the tip :-)